# Facebook Swift SDK compile error when migrate to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, ios10

Due to **iOS 10**, I need to update Xcode to version 8 and Swift 3. There are many compile errors. Spend long hours to trace one by one and eventually there is one I don't know how to fix. Please help.

From the file
FacebookCore | GraphRequestConnection.swift

```
public func add<T: GraphRequestProtocol>(
_ request: T,
batchParameters: [String : AnyObject]?,
completion: ((_ connectionHTTPResponse: HTTPURLResponse?, _ result: GraphRequestResult<T>) -> Void)? = nil) {
sdkConnection.add(request.sdkRequest,
                  completionHandler: completion.map(sdkRequestCompletion),  // compile error here
                         batchParameters: batchParameters)


}
```

> Error Message: Cannot convert call result type '_?' to expected type 'FBSDKGraphRequestHandler!'

I updated the line to

```
completion.map(sdkRequestCompletion) as! FBSDKGraphRequestHandler!
```

but cause segmentation error.

Any advise?

Thanks.